# can I use javascript libraries such as turn.js inside a Adobe Flex project meant for desktop AIR app?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, flash-builder4.5

I want to have a turn effect for several images in an Adobe Flex 4.6 project meant for desktop AIR app.

I have come across http://pageflip.hu/ and http://www.megazine3.de/home.html but I am looking for something I can use in a commercial application without paying for the license.

I want to see if there is a way to use http://www.turnjs.com/#home inside a desktop Adobe Flex 4.6 app.

The images will be stored in the applicationStorageDirectory.

If it is not possible to create a desktop AIR app using javascript turn.js on files stored in localdisk, then what actionscript 3 or flex libraries that have similar effects as turn.js, are available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that turn.js will work well in Flex.

Google says there is a http://www.rubenswieringa.com/blog/flex-book-component-beta